# Insta Edit Mode Lag Problem (Blender 3.3.1)

Tags: edit-mode

This is the second time this is happening to me and I never solved the first time it happended on a different modelling atempt. I've been following Blender Guru's abandoned house tutorial for a while, but trying a few things when modelling the house and just experimenting to improve my skills. For example: I made curved windows and now I'm making a little arch to go on top of each window (see printscreen).

Onto the problem. Edit mode gets insane lag whenever I enter edit mode on the arch. I haven't instanced it or anything yet. it just has a mirror modifier to ensure symmetry. I'm just trying to get a basic shape going. I checked resource monitor and it pegs my CPU to almost 100% instantly when entering edit mode on the arch (see printscreen). Everything was working fine and no lag before this point. I'm on cycles, blender version 3.3.1, rendering is set to GPU. My GPU is an RTX2060, CPU is a Ryzen 5 3600. I don't get what's happening here or how to solve it. Has anyone had that problem before?

The printscreen:
[image]